# Composite Mongo filter agains CosmosDB

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

We are using Mongo C# driver. Locally my backend is a real MongoDB, and on production in Azure - MS CosmosDB with Mongo interface.

My Mongo document has a version. I read the document, modify it, increase the version, write it - and want to be sure that nobody has changed the document between read and write. So I use the version in the update filter:

So I'm doing this:

```
var builder = Builders<SettingsStorage>.Filter;
var filter = builder.Eq(c => c.Id, myId) & builder.Eq(c => c.Version, versionAsReadBeforeUpdate);
await this.configurations.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, updateDef);
```

Or this, just to be sure:

```
var filter1 = Builders<SettingsStorage>.Filter.Eq(c => c.Id, myId);
var filter2 = Builders<SettingsStorage>.Filter.Eq(c => c.Version, versionAsReadBeforeUpdate);
var filter = Builders<SettingsStorage>.Filter.And(filter1, filter2);
await this.configurations.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, updateDef);
```

So if somebody changed the document in between, the version will also change and the filter fail. I'll get "Command findAndModify failed: E11000 duplicate key error collection: configurations Failed _id or unique key constraint" exception and will be able to run retry policies etc.

Now the thing is it works perfect with Mongo backend, but almost always brings this exception when running agains CosmosDB, both when deployed and from the same local environment. It's the same call, it's for sure only one simultaneous caller. So how come? Does the c# driver act differently for CosmosDB? What could I try or how can this be explained?

Note: with a normal filter, i.e. just `builder.Eq(c => c.Id, myId)`, both environments behave the same way and work properly.

Answer (score 0):

CosmosDB is not real MongoDB. It emulates MongoDB. As a result the semantics will vary enormously between real MongoDB and CosmosDB. If you want identical semantics run [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) which also runs in the Azure cloud. The mongod process running locally will be identical to the mongod in the Atlas cloud if you are running the same version of MongoDB. You can choose which version of MongoDB to run when you build your first cluster.

There is a free tier for beginners that is free forever and doesn't require a credit card so give it a spin and see if you get the same semantics.